ggplot color labels with expressions and values
I have the following data:

And I am plotting the value over vds for each different V_gs with the V_gs being of different colors:

My problem is, that I would like the color labels to be formatted nicely like the labels for the axis. Example: 
I have tried to use:
    scale_colour_discrete(
    labels = {function(x) {
        value <- gsub(".*\\.\\.(\\+*)", "\\1", x)
        bquote('U[GS]' ~ ' = ' ~ .(value))}
      }
    ) +

But I then get the following error:
Error in rep(value, length.out = nrows) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'language'

I then tried label_bquote() instead and got the same error but with 'closure'.
Am I on the right track, or is there a different better way, to achieve what I want?
Edit:
@the-mad-statter has already given a working answer, but for anyone coming across this in the future here is the code I have used to get the plot from above.
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

data <- read.csv("Input.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t", quote = "")

data_long <- melt(data, id.vars = "vds", variable.name = "V_gs", value.name = "value")

color_label <- function(x) {
  value <- gsub(".*\\.\\.(\\+*)", "\\1", x)
  bquote('U[GS]' ~ ' = ' ~ .(value))}
}

ggplot(data_long, aes(
  x = vds,
  y = value,
  color = V_gs,
  shape = V_gs
)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(
    x = expression(U[DS]),
    y = expression(U[DS]),
    color = expression(U[GS]),
    shape = expression(U[GS])
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(label = y_scale) +
  scale_x_continuous(label = {
    function(y) {
      paste(y, "V")
    }
  }) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(reverse = T), shape = guide_legend(reverse = T)) +
  scale_colour_discrete(labels = color_label) +
  scale_shape_discrete(labels = color_label) +
  theme_minimal()

And the Input.txt is a .txt file that actually has csv formatted data in it and looks like this:
vds V_"gs"=3V   V_"gs"=3.25V    V_"gs"=3.5V V_"gs"=3.75V    V_"gs"=4V   V_"gs"=4.25V    V_"gs"=4.5V V_"gs"=4.75V    V_"gs"=5V
0.000000000000000e+00   8.923415e-34    8.923415e-34    8.923415e-34    8.923415e-34    8.923415e-34    8.923415e-34    8.923415e-34    8.923415e-34    8.923415e-34
1.000000000000000e+00   6.629273e-02    8.460001e-02    1.005602e-01    1.145959e-01    1.270345e-01    1.381333e-01    1.480970e-01    1.570910e-01    1.652500e-01
2.000000000000000e+00   7.004236e-02    9.939607e-02    1.327373e-01    1.684299e-01    2.003164e-01    2.283812e-01    2.532684e-01    2.754860e-01    2.954397e-01
3.000000000000000e+00   7.004274e-02    9.940270e-02    1.327725e-01    1.697193e-01    2.100430e-01    2.534481e-01    2.992511e-01    3.413388e-01    3.786857e-01
4.000000000000000e+00   7.004237e-02    9.939607e-02    1.327373e-01    1.697194e-01    2.100469e-01    2.534753e-01    2.998012e-01    3.486163e-01    4.001946e-01
5.000000000000000e+00   7.004237e-02    9.939608e-02    1.327373e-01    1.697193e-01    2.100430e-01    2.534481e-01    2.997063e-01    3.486189e-01    4.000209e-01

Created on 2024-04-19 with reprex v2.1.0

Your sample data was a picture so I made up my own.
Your code is not complete so I am unable to reproduce your error message which makes it difficult or impossible to say what went wrong. However, you do have an extra opening curly bracket in the code you did provide.
Regardless, you are on the right track.
I simplified your plotmath syntax but needed to vectorize the labeling function because the function was somehow generating 3 labels for 2 breaks.
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- tibble(
  x = runif(100),
  y = runif(100),
  color = rep(c("V_.gs..3V", "V_.gs..5V"), 50)
)

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = color)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_discrete(
    labels = function(x) {
      sapply(x, function(x) {
        value <- gsub(".*\\.\\.(\\+*)", "\\1", x)
        bquote(U[GS] == .(value))
      })
    }
  )


Created on 2024-04-18 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you, your solution works. I have edited the question to add more information for anyone coming across it in the future.
